# Recommend a Python Library to Automate Web Actions for End Users?

Tags: python, automation

My company a web based ERP system and there are several tedious, repetitive tasks I'd like to automate and seems like it should be fairly easy to do in Python... I've been using the Pandas library and only familiar with the analytical power of Python.

Is there a library anyone would suggest for accomplishing this?

Comment: Check out `selenium-webdriver`, which is a browser-based automation tool with python support.

Comment: @orde, thank you~!  Wanted to mark your comment as the answer but looks like you have to put it in as an answer for me to do that.  If you do, I will mark it as the correct answer.  Thank you for your help, Me

Answer (score 1):

You may try [ClointFusion](https://pypi.org/project/ClointFusion/) which offers 100+ easy to use functions developed using [pyautogui](https://pypi.org/project/PyAutoGUI/), [helium](https://pypi.org/project/helium/) among others.

*Disclaimer: I am one of the Developers of ClointFusion*